# How can I get the all messages in the inbox? (include reply)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-api

i use the following code in Google Apps Script and i wanna get all messages in the inbox. This code gives "Cannot convert Array to number[][]. (line 19, file "Code")" error. How can i fix this code?

```
    var myspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var mysheet = myspreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
    var start = 0;
    var max = 19;
    var count = 0;
    while (count < 7) {
        var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(start, max);
        var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
        //var froms = [];
        messages.get
        for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            var thisThread = threads[i];
            var messages = thisThread.getMessages();
            var messageCount = thisThread.getMessageCount();
            for ( var m = 0; m<=messageCount; m++) {
              var lastMessage = messages[m];
              froms = ([lastMessage.getId(), lastMessage.getSubject(), lastMessage.getTo(), lastMessage.getFrom(), lastMessage.getCc(), JSON.stringify(lastMessage.getDate()), lastMessage.getReplyTo()]);
              mysheet.getRange(1, 1, froms.length, 7).setValues(froms);
              froms = [];
            }
        }
        start = start + 100;
        count++;
        }
}
```

Comment: When setting values with `setValues()` you must create a **two-dimentional array** as this method sets a rectangular grid (N rows and M columns) of values. Use `[[],[],...]` schema (an array with arrays as values) - each element of outer array represents a row and each element of inner arrays represents a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this: `froms = ([lastMessage.getId(), lastMessage.getSubject(), lastMessage.getTo(), lastMessage.getFrom(), lastMessage.getCc(), JSON.stringify(lastMessage.getDate()), lastMessage.getReplyTo()]);`

to this: `froms = ([[lastMessage.getId(), lastMessage.getSubject(), lastMessage.getTo(), lastMessage.getFrom(), lastMessage.getCc(), JSON.stringify(lastMessage.getDate()), lastMessage.getReplyTo()]]);`

But really I think you have even bigger problems with your script.

I'd use something like this.  But I can't test it very well because I don't keep a lot of junk in my inbox.

```
function emailsStuff() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheets()[0];
  sh.clearContents();
  var threads=GmailApp.getInboxThreads() 
  for(var i=0;i<threads.length;i++) {
    var messages=GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
    for(var j=0;j<messages.length;j++) {
      var msg=messages[j];
      sh.appendRow([msg.getId(), msg.getSubject(), msg.getTo(), msg.getFrom(), msg.getCc(), JSON.stringify(msg.getDate()), msg.getReplyTo()]);
    }
  }
}
```